# ¿Por qué la consola me muestra 2 resultados, si solo debería mostrar uno?

Tags: javascript

**En ocasiones no se por qué, en consola marca 2 veces un console.log cuando solo debería ocurrir una vez en la funcion *cargarVaca*, es decir primero se ejecuta la función *cargar* del evento *load* que me dibuja un png que uso de fondo, este a su vez ejecuta la función *dibujar* y dibuja con el *drawImage*, después es cuando sigue *cargarVaca* que también ejecuta el *dibujar*  y dentro del if se verifica que entre a su bloque de código, que es donde tengo el console.log, lo cual indica solo debería pasar una vez, algunas veces si lo hace, otras no, un saludo! **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Villa Platzi</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    
</style>
<body>
    <canvas width="500" height="500" id="lienzo"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function aleatorio(min,max){
            let resultado= Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min;
            return resultado;
        }

        let vp= document.getElementById("lienzo");
        let papel= vp.getContext("2d");
        let mapaRuta= "img/tile.png";

        let vaca={
            url:"img/vaca.png",
            cargaOk: false
        }
        let fondo={
            url:"img/tile.png",
            cargaOk: false//variable flag, la usaremos como señal
        }


        fondo.objeto= new Image();
        fondo.objeto.src= fondo.url;
        fondo.objeto.addEventListener("load",cargar);

        vaca.objeto= new Image();
        vaca.objeto.src= vaca.url;
        vaca.objeto.addEventListener("load",cargarVaca);

        function cargar(){
            fondo.cargaOk=true;
            dibujar();

        }
        function cargarVaca(){
            vaca.cargaOk=true;
            dibujar();
        }

        let n= aleatorio(5,25)

        function dibujar(){
            if(fondo.cargaOk){//cargar cambia la señal de fondo.cargaOk a true, y se dibujara el fondo, para cuando cargarVaca tambien use a dibujar, fondo.cargaOk seguira siendo true, por lo que al dibujarse las vacas, primero se volver a dibujar el fondo de nuevo.
                papel.drawImage(fondo.objeto,0,0);
            }
            if(vaca.cargaOk){
                
                console.log(n);//en ocasiones no se por que, en consola marca 2 veces este log cuando solo deberia ocurrir una vez en el "cargarVaca"
                for(v=0;v<n;v++){
                let x =aleatorio(0,6)*80;//la vaca mide 80x80 pixeles, del rango 0-420 es donde podemos dibujar en el canvas de 500x500
                let y = aleatorio(0,6)*80;//se multiplican *80 para que tengan una "caja" alrededor y asi esten en una especie de grilla y esten separadas unas de otras

                papel.drawImage(vaca.objeto,x,y);
                }
            }
            

        }
        
        
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La primera vez que se ejecuta `cargarVaca()` se cambia el valor de `vaca.cargaOk` a `true` y queda así para siempre por lo que al ejecutar `cargar()`, además de entrar en el primer `if(fondo.cargaOk)` también entra nuevamente en `if(vaca.cargaOk)`.

Sobre el problema de qué algunas veces pasa y otras no, puede ser por qué se están añadiendo 2 addEventListener al mismo evento `load`, este evento puede variar con cada carga de la página.

Fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/load

Comment: "Sobre el problema de qué algunas veces pasa y otras no, puede ser por qué se están añadiendo 2 addEventListener al mismo evento load, este evento puede variar con cada carga de la página." Si puede ser eso, parece algo muy a nivel inferior del lenguaje, gracias!